# HTML5 - Changing video source not working in Safari

Tags: html, video, safari

I have HTML5 videos changing upon clicking different links (see below for code). It works in all browsers but Safari. Initial video is playable in all browsers, but not the switching of videos in Safari. If I modify as so:

```
<script>
function loadAnotherVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    video.src="HTML5 MOVREV.m4v";
    video.load(); // need this for the new video to load
}
function loadAnotherVideo2() {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    video.src="HTML5 MOV.m4v";
    video.load(); // need this for the new video to load
}
</script>
```

It works only in Safari, since its mp4, but does not switch videos fluently while in Safari which mean's its wrong anyway.

It may have to do with the below functions not seeing mp4 in Safari.

CODE: (working in all browsers, but Safari)

```
<div id="VIDEOONE"> <video controls="controls" width="852" height="479">
 <source src="HTML5 MOV.m4v" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="HTML5 MOV.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg">
 video not supported
</video>
<script>
function loadAnotherVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
  sources[0].src = "HTML5 MOVREV.m4v";
  sources[1].src = "HTML5 MOVREV.theora.ogv";
  video.load(); // need this for the new video to load
}
function loadAnotherVideo2() {
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
  sources[0].src = "HTML5 MOV.m4v";
  sources[1].src = "HTML5 MOV.theora.ogv";
  video.load(); // need this for the new video to load
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="video two"
       onclick="loadAnotherVideo()">  

<input type="button" value="video one"
       onclick="loadAnotherVideo2()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

works in all browsers? AFAIK IE9 fails to switch videos via the src() function if you have SOURCE nodes within the video node.

Also, m4v won't play in Firefox and Opera - if you want to switch videos, from my experience it is wise to lose the SOURCE nodes and instead use canPlayType() from the beginning --> even for the initial videos. (be aware that Android 2.2 knows html5 video but did not implement that function --> you would have to implement it if that device is found via the user agent in case its relevant to you. see mediaelement.js for an example-code)

You should not use spaces in your filenames as those can cause errors as well. You probably won't be able to check your player on all common browsers AND operating systems --> Chrome/FF/[...] are not the same on Linux / Windows / Mac

last but not least: why are you using m4v instead of mp4? M4V is only needed if you include chapter information within the file - which the html5 player cannot read anyways. M4V is only needed for iTunes compatible devices together with chapter info.